# How to create a 3D plot?

Tags: plotting

I want to create a 3D plot for these inequality equations:

```
2 | x | -0.6 - y <= 0
2 | z | -0.6 + y <= 0
x, y, z all belong to [-1, +1]
```

I typed:

```
RegionPlot3D[2 | x | -0.6 - y <= 0 && 2 | z | -0.6 + y <= 0, 
             {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}
]
```

and there is always a question:

> RegionPlot3D::boolf: 2|x|-0.6-y<=0&&2|z|-0.6+y<=0 must be a Boolean
>   function.

What should I do? Many thanks!

[image]

Comment: `a|b` is  short for `Alternatives[a,b]`.  `|x|` is invalid syntax.  For absolute value, use `Abs[x]`.

Answer (score 1):

Its not `| x |`, but `Abs[x]`. After that

```
 RegionPlot3D[2 Abs[x] - 0.6 - y <= 0 && 2 Abs[z] - 0.6 + y <= 0, {x, -1, 
  1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}]
```

yields this:

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: The options PlotPoints -> 100, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"  improve the plot under consideration.